# Can I use Yen's k-shortest path algorithm in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I am trying to find if there is an implementation of Yen's k-shortest path algorithm in Memgraph and I can't find it in the documentation. Am I missing something or?
I am using Memgraph 2.7 and I ran it with Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (Memgraph 2.7), there is no implementation of Yen's k-shortest path algorithm, but there is All shortest paths algorithm in Memgraph that is basically an expansion of a classic Dijkstra's algorithm. If I got it right, for k=1, you need Dijkstra and that's Weighted shortest in Memgraph. With All shortest paths you get k=(all paths). There is a missing part of having k=n, for any number of paths.

Here is the [documentation for Weighted shortest path](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/next/reference-guide/built-in-graph-algorithms#weighted-shortest-path) built-in algorithm in Memgraph (Dijkstra) (k=1 in your case). Here is [documentation for All shortest paths](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/next/reference-guide/built-in-graph-algorithms#all-shortest-paths) (k = all paths in your case).